# ag-grid-entreprise problems to use it on angular

Tags: javascript, angular2-routing, ag-grid

I am trying to use ag-grid-enterprise in my application but I can not.

With angular, in app.module.ts I have the following:

```
import { AgGridModule } from "ag-grid-angular/main";
```

and also incorporate

```
import "ag-grid-enterprise/main";
```

in package.json I have

```
"ag-grid-angular": "^8.2.0",
```

(    y además incorporo)
and also incorporate

```
"ag-grid-angular-enterprise": "^13.0.0",
```

without setting license or setting it, compiles me without problems but the app does not load, it gives me the following error:

```
excelCreator.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at __extends (excelCreator.js:8)
    at excelCreator.js:204
    at Object.setPrototypeOf.__proto__ (excelCreator.js:279)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1e9ae7b3a7a54d7fb70d:52)
    at Object.setPrototypeOf.__proto__ (main.js:24)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1e9ae7b3a7a54d7fb70d:52)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (main.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1e9ae7b3a7a54d7fb70d:52)
    at Object.602 (app.component.ts:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1e9ae7b3a7a54d7fb70d:52)
    at Object.582 (main.bundle.js:9123)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1e9ae7b3a7a54d7fb70d:52)
    at Object.1132 (main.bundle.js:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1e9ae7b3a7a54d7fb70d:52)
```

That could be happening?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Solved !!!

Ag-grid package will be 13.3.1 as ag-grid-enterprise version package.

Regards